# Processing HTTP Get response using ajax in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am writing a html to make a REST GET call to underlying service and display the JSON result in tabular format. Below is my attempt at that

```
<html>
    <head>Rides Dashboard View
    </head>
    <body>
         <form name="submitform" id="submitform">
               <input type="submit" value="Refresh">
         </form>
    </body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $('[name="submitform"]').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:7777/ride/dashboard",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    }).done (function(data) { });
    </script>
</html>
```

When I perform submit action, I expect that the resultant JSON data to be alerted but nothing happens. 
Also here is the sample JSON output data

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "requestId": 40,
      "customerId": 123,
      "requestTime": 1502652408000,
      "status": 2,
      "driverId": 1
    },
    {
      "requestId": 41,
      "customerId": 342,
      "requestTime": 1502652425000,
      "status": 2,
      "driverId": 2
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to display it in the tabular format like below

RequestId |  CustomerId | RequestTime  | Status | DriverId

40        |     123     |1502652408000 |   2    |    1

So can someone help me with processing the resultant data from GET request in this tabular format ?

Comment: as result is object you can console it

Comment: example code ? @MuhammadAkberKhan

Comment: console.log(result);, but it will display ut in browser console tab

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan I want it to be displayed on screen not on console tab

Comment: ok, check my answer for displaying on the screen, if any issue, comment on the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create table from json like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('[name="submitform"]').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:7777/ride/dashboard",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            //alert(result);
            var trHTML = '<table><tr><th>RequestId</th><th>CustomerId</th><th>RequestTime</th><th>Status</th><th>DriverId</th></tr>';
            $.each(result.data, function (i, item) {
                    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.requestId + '</td><td>' + item.customerId + '</td><td>' + item.requestTime + '</td><td>' + item.status + '</td><td>' + item.driverId + '</td></tr>';
                });
            trHTML +="</table>";
            $( "body" ).append(trHTML);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: if its helpful for you @Aarish can you upvote the answer?

Comment: @Muhammed: It is the right answer and I marked it. Thanks! And now can you help me with converting the millisecond time to current date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format ?

Comment: oh yes, it might be helpful, var date = new Date(1324339200000);

alert(date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss"));

Comment: Also on subsequent clicks, data is getting appended to html. How do i clear it ?

Comment: ok, for this you create a container div like <div id="tableHolder"></div>,
and replace this line => $( "body" ).append(trHTML); with this one,
$("#tableHolder").html(trHTML);

Comment: Hi Muhammad, can you please check this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674382/making-use-of-http-request-param-in-get-call-using-ajax ?

Comment: @Muhammed: Hi Muhammad, the issue still persists. Can you pls check ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `<script>` tag after closing `</body>` tag at HTML. the solution is to place `<script></script>` before closing `</body>` tag at HTML.

Comment: I am not sure because in one my previous htmls I have written to POST form data using ajax it was similar to this one and it worked fine. Anyway lemme try

Comment: @Aarish The permitted parent elements of [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) element are [Metadata content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Metadata_content) or [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content). Note the error indicated at plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/g4hDFAJAJbeiPsLPyhCZ?p=catalogue.

Comment: @guest271314 actually your example does the opposite.. the `console.log` works, even that it's after the `</body>` element. You sure it's the right plnkr you wanted to put?

Comment: @Dekel Note the red `[X]` error indication at plnkr editor

Comment: It's indeed an error, but it doesn't mean the code will not work.

Comment: @guest271314 It worked but it says [object object] because of the json data. can you please help me with the code for parsing the json and displaying it in tabular format ?

Comment: Set `dataType` to `"json"` or use `$.getJSON()`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "display the JSON result in tabular format."? Where is code where you try to do the same at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I didn't know how to display as I am not well versed with html and js. But one of the answers here helped me do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dekel _"It's indeed an error, but it doesn't mean the code will not work."_ That is the only issue at code at Question. Even without setting `"json"` as `dataType`, there are no other issues at code at Question. One could state that `success` and `.done()` should not both be used, though `.done()` is not used at code at Question and using both does not generate an error.

Comment: "downvote" description? How is the Answer "not useful"?

Comment: "The issue is `<script>` tag after closing `</body>`" I don't know what is the issue, but is't not related to this thing. Thats for sure...

Comment: @Dekel That is the only issue at code at Question. Did you cast "downvote" for the Answer?

Comment: @guest271314 i have, because this answer is not related at all to the problem the OP had. He actually had a problem with the data he got from the server...

Comment: @Dekel OP does not have a "problem" getting the data from server. OP did not write any code to process the data received from server. The only actual problem at code at OP is the erroneous placement of the `<script>` element within HTML.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see it this way. Check the other answer and also this comment in the OP's question: "So can someone help me with processing the resultant data from GET request in this tabular format ?"

Comment: @Dekel That is irrelevant. OP did not write any code in an effort to solve own inquiry. Without the HTML error the Question is off-topic - unless we simply write code for OP without OP trying to write their own code - ignoring  _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."_

Comment: I think this is exactly the case :) he wasn't looking for someone to find a problem, he was looking for someone to solve his homework... the question itself isn't clear enough... You have lots of history here at SO, you know that we see these questions a lot here...

Comment: @Dekel Yes,  addressed the actual error at Question. The "downvote" label states _"This answer is not useful"_, which is not the case with the above Answer. Unless you have the posture that the HTML error should persist without notification to OP that the error exists. Is the Answer "not useful" to OP or other viewers of the Question? If you believe the Answer is "not useful" that is your decision. It is your vote to do with as you please.

Comment: The answer is not useful because it doesn't solve the problem in the question. I can use the exact code (in the question) and I wouldn't need any change based on your answer. Yes - the code will look better and will not have a syntax error in it - but it will not solve the problem (mostly because there isn't any error in the code). The question itself is problematic and should be closed (if not deleted), but I'm afraid the answer is still not relevant.

Comment: @Dekel _"but it will not solve the problem"_ There is no "problem" at code at Question - other than the malformed HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151845/discussion-between-dekel-and-guest271314).