# Making use of HTTP request param in GET call using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http-get

I am writing an HTML page to make a GET call constructing the URL with HTTP request param (`driverid`) to my underlying microservice using AJAX and display results in tabular format in the corresponding divs like below:

```
<html>
    <head>Driver App
    </head>
    <body>
         <form name="submitform" id="submitform">
               <input type="submit" value="Refresh">
         </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var driverid = get("driverid");
    $('[name="submitform"]').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:7777/driver/" + driverid + "/ride",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            //alert(result);

            var waitingHtml = '<table>';
            var ongoingHtml = '<table>'
            var completedHtml = '<table>';

            $.each(result.data, function (i, item) {

                    if (item.status == 0) {
                        var requestTime;
                        if (item.requestTime != 0) {
                            requestTime = new Date(item.requestTime);
                        }

                        var startDate;
                        if (item.startTime != 0) {
                            startDate = new Date(item.startTime);
                        }
                        var endDate;
                        if (item.endTime != 0) {
                            endDate =  new Date(item.endTime);
                        }

                        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.requestId + '</td><td>' + item.customerId + '</td><td>' + requestTime + '</td><td>' + status + '</td><td>' + item.driverId + '</td><td>' + startDate + '</td><td>'
                            + endDate + '</td></tr>';
                        });
                        trHTML +="</table>";
                        $("#WaitingHolder").html(trHTML);
                    } else if (item.status == 1) {
                        var requestTime;
                        if (item.requestTime != 0) {
                            requestTime = new Date(item.requestTime);
                        }

                        var startDate;
                        if (item.startTime != 0) {
                            startDate = new Date(item.startTime);
                        }
                        var endDate;
                        if (item.endTime != 0) {
                            endDate =  new Date(item.endTime);
                        }

                        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.requestId + '</td><td>' + item.customerId + '</td><td>' + requestTime + '</td><td>' + status + '</td><td>' + item.driverId + '</td><td>' + startDate + '</td><td>'
                            + endDate + '</td></tr>';
                        });
                        trHTML +="</table>";
                        $("#OngoingHolder").html(trHTML);
                    } else {
                        var requestTime;
                        if (item.requestTime != 0) {
                            requestTime = new Date(item.requestTime);
                        }

                        var startDate;
                        if (item.startTime != 0) {
                            startDate = new Date(item.startTime);
                        }
                        var endDate;
                        if (item.endTime != 0) {
                            endDate =  new Date(item.endTime);
                        }

                        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.requestId + '</td><td>' + item.customerId + '</td><td>' + requestTime + '</td><td>' + status + '</td><td>' + item.driverId + '</td><td>' + startDate + '</td><td>'
                            + endDate + '</td></tr>';
                        });
                        trHTML +="</table>";
                        $("#CompletedHolder").html(trHTML);
                    }
            }
        }
    }).done (function(data) { });
    });
    </script>

    <table>
    <tr><th>Waiting</th><th>Ongoing</th><th>Completion</th><tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="WaitingHolder">

        </div></td>

        <td><div id="OngoingHolder">

        </div></td>

        <td><div id="CompletedHolder">

        <div></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the sample data which I will be printing in the corresponding div blocks in tabular format:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "requestId": 44,
      "customerId": 234,
      "requestTime": 1502652444000,
      "status": 2,
      "driverId": 5,
      "startTime": 1502652444000,
      "endTime": 1502652744000
    },
    {
      "requestId": 52,
      "customerId": 234234,
      "requestTime": 1502658544000,
      "status": 2,
      "driverId": 5,
      "startTime": 1502658544000,
      "endTime": 1502658844000
    }
  ]
}
```

On making the request, the page just loads with no error in console. Also there is no HTTP call made to the backend. I am not able to fix it with my limited HTML/JS expertise. Can someone help me in getting this fixed?

Comment: Have you debugged this at all? Your question simply states what you're trying to do, and gives no details on what issues you're having

Comment: I have tested it and the page just refreshes.I don't see the request being sent to backend.

Comment: Do you really need Ajax? to specify: if you do not need need the page to get real time information, you will not need ajax. "div blocks in tabular format" I would suggest to use XML or JSON. Simply because you could use "simpler" already existing codes for example a DOMparser (XML).
OR you could check-out firebase, it's a free "easy to use" database from google, it's easier, but more limited.

Comment: Okay i see. Can you help me with sample code ?

Comment: is the form "submit" event being handled? You can easily check this with an alert on the first line of the handler function. This is the kind of basic debugging info which is being referred to in the first comment.

Comment: You can try https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_intro.asp
It really helped me!

Answer (score -1):

there are some logical errors in your code, i have sorted,

```
<html>
    <head>Driver App
    </head>
    <body>
         <form name="submitform" id="submitform">
               <input type="submit" value="Refresh">
         </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var driverid = get("driverid");
    $('[name="submitform"]').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:7777/driver/" + driverid + "/ride",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            //alert(result);

            var waitingHtml = '<table>';
            var ongoingHtml = '<table>'
            var completedHtml = '<table>';

            $.each(result.data, function (i, item) {

                    if (item.status == 0) {
                        var requestTime;
                        if (item.requestTime != 0) {
                            requestTime = new Date(item.requestTime);
                        }

                        var startDate;
                        if (item.startTime != 0) {
                            startDate = new Date(item.startTime);
                        }
                        var endDate;
                        if (item.endTime != 0) {
                            endDate =  new Date(item.endTime);
                        }

                        waitingHtml += '<tr><td>' + item.requestId + '</td><td>' + item.customerId + '</td><td>' + requestTime + '</td><td>' + status + '</td><td>' + item.driverId + '</td><td>' + startDate + '</td><td>'
                            + endDate + '</td></tr>';

                    } else if (item.status == 1) {
                        var requestTime;
                        if (item.requestTime != 0) {
                            requestTime = new Date(item.requestTime);
                        }

                        var startDate;
                        if (item.startTime != 0) {
                            startDate = new Date(item.startTime);
                        }
                        var endDate;
                        if (item.endTime != 0) {
                            endDate =  new Date(item.endTime);
                        }

                        ongoingHtml += '<tr><td>' + item.requestId + '</td><td>' + item.customerId + '</td><td>' + requestTime + '</td><td>' + status + '</td><td>' + item.driverId + '</td><td>' + startDate + '</td><td>'
                            + endDate + '</td></tr>';

                    } else {
                        var requestTime;
                        if (item.requestTime != 0) {
                            requestTime = new Date(item.requestTime);
                        }

                        var startDate;
                        if (item.startTime != 0) {
                            startDate = new Date(item.startTime);
                        }
                        var endDate;
                        if (item.endTime != 0) {
                            endDate =  new Date(item.endTime);
                        }

                        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.requestId + '</td><td>' + item.customerId + '</td><td>' + requestTime + '</td><td>' + status + '</td><td>' + item.driverId + '</td><td>' + startDate + '</td><td>'
                            + endDate + '</td></tr>';

                    }

            });
                    waitingHtml+='</table>';
                    $("#WaitingHolder").html(waitingHtml);
                    ongoingHtml+='</table>';
                    $("#OngoingHolder").html(ongoingHtml);
                    completedHtml+='</table>';
                    $("#CompletedHolder").html(completedHtml);

        }
    });
    </script>
    <div id="WaitingHolder"></div>
    <div id="OngoingHolder"></div>
    <div id="CompletedHolder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Muhammed: It doesn't fix the issue

Comment: From where you are  getting driver id, have you checked json response is it fine?

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan according the original question "Also there is no HTTP call made to the backend". So the problem is likely to be _before_ the ajax request is made, not afterwards. Whilst your changes may well be useful, they appear not to address the root of the problem.

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan I am calling thehtml call  http://localhost:7777/driverapp.html?driverid=5  with driver id as request param

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan Can you pls check and let me know ?

Comment: are you getting driverid correctly? var driverid = get("driverid"); can you alert it ?

Comment: Have you checked it?